# How can I get an average number of hits per unique IP address over a period of time in Kibana / Elasticsearch?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, aggregation, kibana

I'm using Elasticsearch and Kibana to log requests to a few webservers, and I've already setup GROK'ing so that IP addresses of clients are contained in the field: "geoip.ip".

I'm using Kibana 4 and Elasticsearch 1.6.

My question is, how can I graph the average number of page views per IP address over a period of time?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078798/how-to-graph-average-number-of-page-views-per-person-per-time-unit-using-elas) question here which seems to be asking the same thing, but it was never answered.

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana 4 you can create a line visualization that will use the "terms" aggregation on the "geoip.ip" field, if each page view is one event entry in Kibana than you can use the count option instead of an average.

If the number of page views is a value in a different field, just choose average instead of count and select the correct field.

to perform this over time you'll need to use the "Date Histogram" aggregation.

Read this post for more information:
[Kibana Tutorial](https://www.timroes.de/2015/02/07/kibana-4-tutorial-part-3-visualize/)